# EL1046E:(pos 45): Cannot find terminating for string

Tags: java, mongodb

My regular expression pattern sits in a mongo database.
The pattern is

```
('/[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\s\\-,']{1,45}/')
```

I'm trying to evaluate an expression by passing the input string.

It's throwing a Spel Exception:

> **CAUSE:org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1046E:(pos 45): Cannot find terminating  for string.
>   MESSAGE: NON_TERMINATING_QUOTED_STRING**

But my pattern looks good: it should allow A-Z,a-z,0-9,.,special characters,-,,,', 1 to 45 chars.

Here's the Java code:

```
public boolean isFirstNameValid(String regex) {
     Pattern firstNamePattern = Pattern.compile(regex); 
     Matcher firstNameMatcher = firstNamePattern.matcher(firstName);
     return firstNameMatcher.matches(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code throwing the error?

Comment: public boolean isFirstNameValid(String regex) {
        Pattern firstNamePattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher firstNameMatcher = firstNamePattern.matcher(firstName);
        return firstNameMatcher.matches();

    }

Comment: Added code from comment

Comment: Try replacing the `'` character with `''`.

Comment: @shmosel its worked thanks